# Maven Java Web Application Mapping with jersey

Tags: java, maven, url, jersey, mapping

Somehow it doesn't work properly

If I am right it should be possible to call `showLogin()` using `projectURI/rest/application/login`

But somehow it doesn't work out that way. I guess something went wrong in here/

ApplicationController:

```
package de.tc;

import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/application")
public class ApplicationController {

    @GET
    @Path("/login")
    public Response showLogin() {
        String output = "login";
        System.out.println("called");
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

<display-name>application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
            </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>de.tc</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

a URL need to look like:

domain/nameOfProject/rest/pathOfServlet

example `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldProject/rest/application/login`

please try to remove the "/" in your path annotation.

you wrote:

```
@Path("/application")
@Path("/login")
```

try:

```
 @Path("application")
 @Path("login")
```

please dont forget:

1. configure your project by server->"add and remove".
2. before trying to call a Servlet, you must start the server(like tomcat).